# Sub "worksheet_calculate()" not updating automatically when taking data from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a sheet, which shows color of user defined RAL. I have 2 sheets: "data" and "Sheet1". The data sheet contains table of RAL colors (+ some other source data, nor relevant to this problem) - the table is named "Color" and looks like this:

[image: Table]

In Sheet1 I have a cell (B10), which is allowed to contain only data from table "Color[RAL]" (using Data validation functionality).

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculation()

    Range("F10").Interior.Color = RGB( _
        Application.VLookup(Range("B10"), Worksheets("data").Range("F1:J214"), 3), _
        Application.VLookup(Range("B10"), Worksheets("data").Range("F1:J214"), 4), _
        Application.VLookup(Range("B10"), Worksheets("data").Range("F1:J214"), 5) _
    )

End sub
```

I  originally wanted to use something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculation()

    Range("F10").Interior.Color = RGB( _
        Application.VLookup(Range("B10"), color[RAL], 3), _
        Application.VLookup(Range("B10"), color[RAL], 4), _
        Application.VLookup(Range("B10"), color[RAL], 5) _
    )

End sub
```

However that would not compile. Therefore, I have decided to go with hardcoding the range, since it won't be changed often and there is no problem changing the range in the code.

Anyway, when I apply the same code (the first of the above), while the arguments for VLookup are in the same sheet (data table + "check cell"), all works as expected - I change the value in cell (also using the Data validation functionality) and the desired cell changes its color.

The moment I move the table to a different sheet, it does not get refreshed automatically - I need to run the Sub manually to get the color changed. It does not even change when I manually recalculate the worksheet (or workbook).

Any ideas why this behavior is occurring and how to fix it?

Bonus question :) - is there a way to actually refer to table Color, column RAL, in the VLookup, instead of hardcoding the Range?

Comment: Put a formula in F10 to begin with, and delete your handlers. `RGB()` is `b*65536 + g*256 + r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is the `Worksheet_Calculation()` is no event and therefore does not run automatically. Therefore you must use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event. This is within a specific sheet. So if you move the table to anther sheet you will also need to move the `Worksheet_Calculation()` event to that sheet or the code will still apply to the old sheet.

To avoid moving the code you could use `Workbook_SheetCalculate` event in `ThisWorkbook` which runs when **any** of all the sheets re-calculates.

For your bonus question have a look at [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) or use the `Range("Color[RAL]")` to access the data range in column `RAL` of table `Color`.

Comment: `Worksheet_Calculation` is not even an event handler, it should be `Worksheet_Calculate`.

Comment: @GSerg well spotted. I will change it. Thanks!

Comment: When I create Workbook_SheetCalculate event in ThisWorkbook, using:

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate()

Worksheets("List1").Range("F10").Interior.Color = RGB( _
        Application.VLookup(Worksheets("List1").Range("B10"), Worksheets("data").Range("F1:J214"), 3), _
        Application.VLookup(Worksheets("List1").Range("B10"), Worksheets("data").Range("F1:J214"), 4), _
        Application.VLookup(Worksheets("List1").Range("B10"), Worksheets("data").Range("F1:J214"), 5))
End Sub

I get "procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Comment: sorry for the terrible formatting above, not sure how to actually format nicely in Answer field.

Comment: Because [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetcalculate) it must be `Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)`. Reading the manuals always helps. I recommend to add as first line `If Sh.Name <> "List1" Then Exit Sub` so the code only runs on the calculation of sheet `List1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still does not work as expected, however when I put `=RANDBETWEEN(1;10)` to some cell, the recalculation triggers (does not otherwise). Since this is ok with me, I consider this to be solved. Thanks again